# I2C comunication in STM32

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, i2c

My question is simple, I just want to send 20 bytes of data from a STM32F103C8 blue phill card in i2c slave mode to a raspberry pi 3 in master mode, I use STM32Cube IDE can any other IDE work for me. After browsing the web, I don't fully understand everything necessary for this. Thank you,

I add source code that I am testing, at the moment it does not work for me and I want to know what may be wrong,

```
#include "main.h"

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

//#define MASTER_BOARD
#define I2C_ADDRESS        0x30F

#define RXBUFFERSIZE    20

/* USER CODE END PD */

//#define I2C_SPEEDCLOCK   100000
#define I2C_DUTYCYCLE    I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

uint8_t aTxBuffer[] = " ****I2C_TwoBoards communication based on IT****  ****I2C_TwoBoards communication based on IT**** ";

uint8_t aRxBuffer[RXBUFFERSIZE];

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

int main(void) {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    HAL_Init();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

    /* USER CODE END Init */

    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

    /* USER CODE END SysInit */

    /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_I2C1_Init();
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

    if (HAL_I2C_Init(&I2cHandle) != HAL_OK) {
        /* Initialization Error */
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /* USER CODE END 2 */

    /* Infinite loop */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    while (1) {
        /* USER CODE END WHILE */

        /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    }
    /* USER CODE END 3 */

    if(HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT(&I2cHandle, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer, RXBUFFERSIZE) != HAL_OK)
      {
        /* Transfer error in reception process */
        Error_Handler();
      }
//**************************************************************************************************
    while (HAL_I2C_GetState(&I2cHandle) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY)
      {
      }
//**************************************************************************************************
    if(HAL_I2C_Slave_Transmit_IT(&I2cHandle, (uint8_t*)aTxBuffer, TXBUFFERSIZE)!= HAL_OK)
      {
        /* Transfer error in transmission process */
        Error_Handler();
      }
//**************************************************************************************************
    while (HAL_I2C_GetState(&I2cHandle) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY)
      {
      }
//**************************************************************************************************

    if(Buffercmp((uint8_t*)aTxBuffer,(uint8_t*)aRxBuffer,RXBUFFERSIZE))
      {
        /* Processing Error */
        Error_Handler();
      }

}

/**
 * @brief System Clock Configuration
 * @retval None
 */
void SystemClock_Config(void) {
    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = { 0 };
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = { 0 };

    /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks
     */
    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks
     */
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
            | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

    if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

/**
 * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void) {

    /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

    /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
    hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
    hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
    hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
    hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
    hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
    hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
    hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
    hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
    hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

    /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
 * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void) {

    /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
 * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
 * @retval None
 */
void Error_Handler(void) {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
    /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

    /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: Please refer to this guide and reformat your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  Your questions is way too broad.  What have you tried?  How is it hooked up?  What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

The question is broad so I will answer about the methodology to solve this kind of problems.

Try to narrow this down into smaller steps, each step could be broken down to smaller steps or even generate new questions here.

1. find a STM32 I2C slave example, build and flash it.

   1. how to run a blinky example on STM32
   2. how to open i2c port
   3. connect your oscilloscope and observe output
2. read any data from RPi

   1. Can you read data from a known good slave?
3. connect the devices
4. modify slave code to send custom data.
5. write the application on your raspberry pi

Comment: I appreciate your response. It is true what you say, at this moment I have 8 ultrasonic sensors connected to the stm32 card and I can verify their data readings through the STlink and stm32 studio. By configuring the STM32MX I enabled "everything" I need, including the i2c pins but after that, testing with some commands from the HAL library I can't even create the link with an Arduino Uno. I don't have an oscilloscope on hand due to that my university is closed due to the issue of covid-19, but I appreciate all the advice you can give me ...

Comment: Continue to divide the problem into smaller parts remove what is not needed.

Comment: I added the code from the main.c file to the post. I simplified everything by just sending a character string through i2c, it does not work for me, it would be very helpful if you could check it, I look forward to your recommendations ...

(I am using the google translator in case you do not understand very well what I write, my native language is Spanish)

Comment: without a logic analyzer you are blind, I would try to find a way to see if slave receive is triggered.